# What ruby based forum software would you recommend for integration into an existing rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forum, forums

What ruby based forum software would you recommend for integration into an existing rails application and allows single sign-on? I have seen many suggestions in posts for forum software that is no longer maintained (2008 and earlier).

Answer (score 2):

Beast is the most current one I know of, and I'm sure it's the one you are referencing.

The rest is more of a side note, but, when I first got into rails, i asked similar questions, aka, what is the best blog, cms, forum, etc to use? As it turns out, the Rails community as a whole is interested in use cases that fit outside the plug-n-play web apps, so most people will end up rolling their own to fit their needs exactly if they find occasion to build such an app in Rails. The good news is that I think that I remember hearing that beast is like 800 lines of code, so it can't been too burdensome to either upgrade out of 2.2ish rails or just copy over the logic you need for your forum.

Answer (score 1):

[Thredded](https://thredded.org/) is very actively maintained!

Thredded is a Rails engine, so it is very easy to integrate it into an existing app.

[image: Thredded demo screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

http://github.com/radar/rboard

Rboard is really pretty awesome. :)

Answer (score 0):

I always refer to Ruby Toolbox on what the rails comunity prefers.
Here's a good reference http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/forum_systems.html

Based on the list there are two projects

1. Rboard - last commit 25 days ago
2. altered_beast - last commit 12 months ago

I agree with Jed Schneider, in the end most rails guys will roll out their own to fit the exact needs.

Answer (score 0):

**Forem** and **Discourse** look promising:

https://github.com/radar/forem

https://github.com/discourse/discourse